# LWC lightning-accordion how to change CSS of the summary heading for open sections?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, slds

I have an accordion implemented in lightning data table, and I want to change the style (background color) of the accordion Summary whenever the section is opened.
I didn't know how to implement a CSS for the opened section.
I tried the (Styling Hooks) below but it didn't work:

```
.THIS .slds-is-open > .slds-accordion__summary-heading {
  background-color: var(--sds-c-accordion-summary-color-background, red);
  }
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! In order to better assist you, you should provide some code to demonstrate what you've done so far (you can [edit] your post to include this information). Please read about [ask] and take the [tour] so you know what is expected of your question. We'll be happy to help you once we have more information.

Comment: original post amended to include some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's now how that works. You should specify the selector to use, and the hook you wish to modify. Normally, this will be something like:

```
.slds-is-open {
  --sds-c-accordion-summary-color-background: red;
}
```

The [documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/) explains how it works in the background, using the CSS var() function, but the part you need to focus on is setting the value.

---

To get this to work, you have to set a property you have access to. After some experimentation, I came up with the following code:

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class Q320026lwc extends LightningElement {
  sections = [
    { title: "Section 1", body: "Section 1 Content", id: "1" },
    { title: "Section 2", body: "Section 2 Content", id: "2" },
    { title: "Section 3", body: "Section 3 Content", id: "3" },
    { title: "Section 4", body: "Section 4 Content", id: "4" },
  ];
  onsectiontoggle(event) {
    let openSections = event.detail.openSections;
    let sections = this.template.querySelectorAll(
      "lightning-accordion-section"
    );
    sections.forEach((section) => {
      section.dataset.open = !!(openSections.indexOf(section.name) > -1);
    });
  }
}
```

---

```
<template>
    <lightning-accordion onsectiontoggle={onsectiontoggle}>
        <lightning-accordion-section name={section.id} label={section.title} for:each={sections} for:item="section"
            key={section.id}>
            {section.body}
        </lightning-accordion-section>
    </lightning-accordion>
</template>
```

---

```
[data-open="true"] {
  --sds-c-accordion-summary-color-background: red;
}
```

We use the sectiontoggle event to determine what's open, then attach a custom data element to the section. We can use this attribute to trigger the custom CSS.

Comment: the above selector didn't work. I will post my HTML template:  

 `<lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open   onsectiontoggle={handleToggleSection}>
            <template if:true={topics}>
                <template for:each={topics} for:item="topic">
                    <lightning-accordion-section name={topic.Id} label={topic.Name} key={topic.Id} >                     
                    </lightning-accordion-section>
                </template>
             </template>
        </lightning-accordion>`

Comment: @Tania-MariaDib It may need to be `:host .slds-is-open`. I haven't used it yet, I'm just going on the documentation.

Comment: I tried :host, and it is not working as well ... i read the documentation .. but didn't figure out how to change the summary backgroud once the section is opened.

Comment: @Tania-MariaDib I wonder if this is a new Summer 21 feature that isn't globally available yet? I'll see if I can make something work.

Comment: @Tania-MariaDib I figured it out. It requires a little help from some code, but the new version should work as advertised.

Comment: thank you so much, the suggested solution worked for me.